# Powershell Files fetch

Tags: powershell, scripting

Am looking for some help to create a PowerShell script.

I have a folder where I have lots of files, I need only those file that has below two content inside it:

1. must have any matching string pattern as same as in file  file1 (the content of file 1 is `-IND 23042528525` or `INDE 573626236` or `DSE3523623` it can be more strings like this)
2. also have date inside the file in between `03152022` and `03312022` in the format `mmddyyyy`.
   file could be old so nothing to do with creation time.

then save the result in csv containing the path of the file which fulfill above to conditions.

Currently am using the below command that only gives me the file which fulfilling the 1 condition.

```
$table = Get-Content C:\Users\username\Downloads\ISIN.txt
Get-ChildItem `
    -Path E:\data\PROD\server\InOut\Backup\*.txt `
    -Recurse |
    Select-String -Pattern ($table)|
    Export-Csv C:\Users\username\Downloads\File_Name.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: You have a lot of requirements for such little code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if a file contains a certain keyword from a range of keywords, you can use regex for that. If you also want to find at least one valid date in format 'MMddyyyy' in that file, you need to do some extra work.

Try below:

```
# read the keywords from the file. Ensure special characters are escaped and join them with '|' (regex 'OR')
$keywords  = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\ISIN.txt' | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
# create a regex to capture the date pattern (8 consecutive digits)
$dateRegex = [regex]'\b(\d{8})\b'  # \b means word boundary
# and a datetime variable to test if a found date is valid
$testDate   = Get-Date
# set two variables to the start and end date of your range (dates only, times set to 00:00:00)
$rangeStart = (Get-Date).AddDays(1).Date   # tomorrow
$rangeEnd   = [DateTime]::new($rangeStart.Year, $rangeStart.Month, 1).AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)  # end of the month

# find all .txt files and loop through. Capture the output in variable $result
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\data\PROD\server\InOut\Backup'-Filter '*.txt'-File -Recurse |
ForEach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw
    # first check if any of the keywords can be found
    if ($content -match $keywords) {
        # now check if a valid date pattern 'MMddyyyy' can be found as well
        $dateFound = $false
        $match = $dateRegex.Match($content)
        while ($match.Success -and !$dateFound) {
            # we found a matching pattern. Test if this is a valid date and if so
            # set the $dateFound flag to $true and exit the while loop
            if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($match.Groups[1].Value, 
                                          'MMddyyyy',[CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture, 
                                          [System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles]::None, 
                                          [ref]$testDate)) {
                # check if the found date is in the set range
                # this tests INCLUDING the start and end dates
                $dateFound = ($testDate -ge $rangeStart -and $testDate -le $rangeEnd)
            }
            $match = $match.NextMatch()
        }
        # finally, if we also successfully found a date pattern, output the file
        if ($dateFound) { $_.FullName }
        elseif ($content -match '\bUNKNOWN\b') {
            # here you output again, because unknown was found instead of a valid date in range
            $_.FullName
        }
    }
}

# result is now either empty or a list of file fullnames
$result | set-content -Path 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\MatchedFiles.txt'
```

Comment: Hi, but it will search if the date pattern is there but i want only those which have date from range(03222022-03312022 that the future date)

Comment: @vikaspaul Ok, I have added code for testing if the valid date is in range

Comment: thank a lot it works perfect for me, just have small question if i want to search the file with the keywords in the ISIN and  date is like UNKNOWN

Comment: @vikaspaul Glad to hear my answer worked for you. Being new to the platform you may not know this, but it is customary to mark the question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left. For your extra requirement, simply add an `else {..}` after `if ($dateFound)....` and output whatever you want when the date was not in range (unknown)

Comment: @theo- no i think you didnt understand files that we are searching some have date range that we already solve but for other we dont have date but instead of date it is like UNKNOWN keyword inside the file, so i want to search those too which have ISIN number same as in the file but date is (UNKNOWN), so in that case i dont need to create a seperate script for both.

Comment: @vikaspaul Ok, final update. It now also outputs if no valid date in range was found, but instead the word 'UNKNOWN'

Comment: Is it possible to search for the file with name like XDTE\\UNWN instead of UNKNOWN?

Comment: Hi again, thanks for helping me with this as am new in scripting but you almost solve the problem, i have one small req i want to search the file which have same ISIN as in input fille ($keywords  = (Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\username\Downloads\ISIN.txt')and if ISIN exists search if one of the 2 pattern(XDTE // UKNW, or EFFD//UKWN) is also there and then show the file name or path.

Comment: @vikaspaul just put these two patterns in a regex string `$unknown = '\b(XDTE//UKNW|EFFD//UKWN)\b'` and use that in the `elseif ($content -match $unknown) {...}`

Comment: Or if possible to give result according the pattern or ISIN present in the file like
if ISIN abc is present in the file i want result likebelow
abd  file path